# Adding extra <li> to existing <ul> on Facebook homepage

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a Chrome plugin to modify the Facebook homepage.

How would I add an extra `<li>` to the `<ul>` with a class of `_54nf`?

Here's my current code:

```
function addLabel()
{
var ul = document.getElementsByClassName("_54nf");
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Test"));
ul.appendChild(li); // line 6
}

addLabel();
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I presume the problem is `getElementsByClassName` but I'm not sure.

Comment: `getElement>>>s<<<ByClassName` returns a collection. Use a loop.

Comment: Just curious but is this legal?...

Comment: @War10ck Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @Juhana Dunno, that's why I asked. Seem's quirky to manipulate someone else's site.

Comment: It's manipulating a document on the user's own computer, and a user can do whatever they want with documents they've downloaded.

Comment: It's as legal as buying a newspaper and drawing moustaches to everyone in the pictures.

Comment: @War10ck If you're only doing this in your own browser, it's fine. If you're embedding FB into your page and modifying it, that might be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a list of nodes (notice the plural `s`). Use:

```
var ul = document.getElementsByClassName("_54nf")[0];
```

to index down to just the first one.

This assumes there's only one such element on the page, or you only want to modify the first one.

Comment: Or... `document.querySelector("._54nf")`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your reply. When I try this I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined` on line 6. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: That means that `getElementsByClassName` isn't finding anything that matches the class you gave. Are you sure you got the class name right? Does this class always exist? If not, you need to test `ul.length` before trying to use it.

Comment: Yep, if you search the source of the Facebook homepage there's a `<ul class="_54nf" role="menu">` there every time.